# MySQL Recursive Select Query with unknown number of result set columns

Tags: mysql

I have been looking for a solution for the last few hours.

Here is some data to help explain this problem:

```
mysql> describe REGION_FEATURE;
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID                    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| REGION_ID             | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | 
| NAME                  | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| FILENAME_NOMENCLATURE | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| CONFIG_FILE_TYPE      | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
| ITERATOR_GROUP        | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                | 
+-----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> select * from REGION_FEATURE;
+----+-----------+----------------+-----------------------+------------------+----------------+
| ID | REGION_ID | NAME           | FILENAME_NOMENCLATURE | CONFIG_FILE_TYPE | ITERATOR_GROUP |
+----+-----------+----------------+-----------------------+------------------+----------------+
|  1 |         1 | MaxCpe01       | c01                   |                0 |              1 | 
|  2 |         1 | MaxCpe05       | c05                   |                0 |              1 | 
|  3 |         1 | PrivacyEnable  | pe                    |                0 |              2 | 
|  4 |         1 | PrivacyDisable | pd                    |                0 |              2 |
```

I need to write a query that will give the result in this way.  I am expecting 4 rows, but the N number of combinations.

rows with the same interator_group(I_G) are not combined. In this example it's I_G =1 x I_G=2 but there can be N number of I_G

```
I_G=1 x I_G=n x I_G=...


MaxCpe01 | PrivacyEnable

MaxCpe01 | PrivacyDisable

MaxCpe05 | PrivacyEnable

MaxCpe05 | PrivacyDisable
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: you should try to better elaborate your desired results to get an answer because right now its not clear what you want to retrieve actually.

Comment: In the example above, I need to build file name combinations by concatenating, but I may have more than 2 Iterator Groups.  In the above example I have 2, but I can have 3, 4 ,5 and so forth.

Comment: In the example above, I need to build file name combinations by concatenation, but I may have more than 2 Iterator Groups.  In the above example I have 2, but I can have 3, 4 ,5 and so forth. MaxCPE01_PrivacyEnable , MaxCPE01_PrivacyDisable, MaxCPE05_PrivacyEnable, MaxCPE05_PrivacyDisable.  But I could have , MaxCPE01_PrivacyDisable_<IteratorGroup_3> and so forth.  i am looking for a single row result without having to cycle thru the table multiple times to create these permutations.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```sql
SELECT t1.name name1, t2.name name2
  FROM region_feature t1 CROSS JOIN region_feature t2
 WHERE t1.iterator_group <> t2.iterator_group
   AND t1.id < t2.id
 ORDER BY name1;
```

Output:

```
|    NAME1 |          NAME2 |
|----------|----------------|
| MaxCpe01 | PrivacyDisable |
| MaxCpe01 |  PrivacyEnable |
| MaxCpe05 | PrivacyDisable |
| MaxCpe05 |  PrivacyEnable |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e9522/7)** demo

Comment: Yes, but the result will only render 2 columns, I need it to be dynamic.  In the example above, I need to build file name combinations by concatenation, but I may have more than 2 Iterator Groups.  In the above example I have 2, but I can have 3, 4 ,5 and so forth. MaxCPE01_PrivacyEnable , MaxCPE01_PrivacyDisable, MaxCPE05_PrivacyEnable, MaxCPE05_PrivacyDisable.  I may have , MaxCPE01_PrivacyDisable_<IteratorGroup_3> and so forth.  I am looking for a single row result without having to cycle thru the table multiple times to create these permutations.